# How to Write to Server from an ePub Book

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, epub, epub3

Is there a way to write data to a server from within an ePub book?

I am trying to create an interactive activity to go along with some book content and I would like to write the user's responses in the activity to a DB on a server.

I am good with all the JavaScript for the activity and all the server-side code for the DB; but I just can't seem to figure out how to get the data from the ePub book to the server. If it is even possible?

I have tried using jQuery with AJAX and I have also tried to use a XMLHttpRequest.

The closest thing I have gotten to work resulted in an error message: error on line XXXX at column XXXX: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Here is a code snippet:

```
var objRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

objRequest.open("POST", "http://www.example.com/write.php?action=yes", false);
objRequest.send();

if (objRequest.status != 200 && objRequest.status != 0) {
  alert("error");
} else {
  alert("success");
}
```

I believe the error is being reported on the IF statement line. Neither of my ALERT statements fire.

Just as a note, this works perfectly fine in a browser. Just not in the compiled ePub package.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're viewing the document in an eBook reader with internet connection, and it has a JavaScript environment with `XMLHttpRequest`? I wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: We can only help and advise you if you post your current code, otherwise the errormessages are useless for us.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't quite understand your comment. Yes, ePub allows for HTML5 and JavaScript to be used in the book. Many different eBook readers (iBooks for example) support this. I have created many "interactive" activities for books in the past. I am not trying to write to a server for the first time. And, encountering the issue I posted above.

Comment: OK, I thought they were quite static (only HTML+CSS). However, without your code we won't be able to help you with the issue - it currently is not even clear how you got this error.

Comment: You're right @Bergi - Sorry, I just posted a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. It looks a bit like a XML parse error, could you show us the HTTP response?

Comment: That's the problem, I am not getting a response. Neither of my alerts fire. It is erroring before that.

Comment: Don't you have any debugging tools? At least fiddler?

Comment: No, there are no debugging tools (at least none that I know of) that are within iBooks or any of the other ePub readers. Typically, (in the case of iBooks) I use Safari to test everything in and then it runs 99.999% correctly in iBooks.

Comment: Are all your files declared in the OPF (jQuery, etc.)? Also, make sure you've got the .xhtml file declared with a 'scripted' property.

Comment: As of 2015, there is now a switch (disabled by default) in the iBook preferences that seems to allow or deny loading resources from the Internet – maybe this would also enable XHR?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, Apple won't let you get any data from the internet to your epub (in iBooks at least).

Still in iBooks, you can't send data from your epub using POST requests. The only way you can send data to the internet is using a GET request, and i think you can do that only by making a simple link, and not using an AJAX request.

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/myfile.php?mydata=12324&my_other_data=foo">
Send data to myfile.php
</a>
```

I don't know if it is the same thing for other epub readers... but Apple just locked iBooks.

Just tell me if i'm wrong, i'm interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will allow remote connections if you package the book in iBooks author and create the JavaScript as a HTML widget. I have tried doing the same, and got headaches trying to get it to work with epub. Give it a shot with widgets and iBooks author, my book even has automatic updating in the background for new data. Trevor Burnham has an excellent widget template you can use here: https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/iBooks-HTML-Widget-Boilerplate